# Взаимодействия по https используя ГОСТ сертификат

Tags: python, django

Я получаю ошибку рукопожатия при попытке выполнить запрос. Вот код:

```
request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Authorization': 
'token ' + token}
post_data = {'document': doc_base64, 'sign': doc_signature, 'request_id': 
request_id}
data = json.dumps(post_data)
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'GOST2012-GOST8912- 
GOST8912'
session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
session.verify = 'D:/mdlp/cert.pem'
response = 
session.post('https://api.stage.mdlp.crpt.ru/api/v1/documents/send', 
data=data, headers=header)
content = json.loads(response.content)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 227, in process_exception_by_middleware
response = middleware_method(request, exception)
File "C:/Users/amotov/IdeaProjects/kmisregion_backend\common\middleware.py", line 23, in process_exception
raise exception
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:/Users/amotov/IdeaProjects/kmisregion_backend\pharmacy\integration\mdlp\views.py", line 47, in send_doc
document_id = utils.make_request_for_doc(doc_base64, doc_signature, token)
File "C:/Users/amotov/IdeaProjects/kmisregion_backend\pharmacy\integration\mdlp\utils.py", line 123, in make_request_for_doc
response = session.post('https://api.stage.mdlp.crpt.ru/api/v1/documents/send', data=data, headers=header)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 581, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 314, in connect
cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 268, in create_urllib3_context
context.set_ciphers(ciphers or DEFAULT_CIPHERS)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 406, in set_ciphers
self._ctx.set_cipher_list(ciphers)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1198, in set_cipher_list
'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256'
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 67, in openssl_assert
exception_from_error_queue(error)
File "C:\python_venv\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
raise exception_type(errors)
```

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Подскажите, плз, что я делаю не так.

Comment: В вашей «ошибке» отсутствует сам текст ошибки, похоже вы не скопировали её до конца

Comment: OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [] [27/Feb/2019 12:18:52] "POST /api/pharmacy/integration/mdlp/send-doc/ HTTP/1.1" 500 191538